# Renumbering tetrahedral dice but retaining the probabilities

Tags: geometry, statistics

Let us have two regular tetrahedrons, with numbers *1,2,3,4* written on their sides.

We "throw" this object and play with it, like with the regular cube, and the side on the bottom counts as our point. It's easy to see that with 25% chance, we throw *1,2,3, or 4.*

Now we should make two tetrahedrons, which are different from these two, and write positive integers on their side, it is 25% to throw either of them, and if we throw with both of them, we have the same chance for the sum of our throws, like with our regular tetrahedrons.

It is quite hard to understand, but here is the case:

We have these several cases:

- 1 case -> We throw **1** with both of them, when the sum is **2.**
- 2 cases -> We throw **1,2** or **2,1** with them, when the sum is **3**.
- 3 cases -> We throw **1,3** or **2,2** or **3,1** with them, when the sum is **4**.
- 4 cases -> We throw **1,4** or **2,3** or **3,2** or **4,1** with them, when sum is **5.**
- 3 cases -> We throw **2,4** or **3,3** or **4,2**  with them, when the sum is **6.**
- 2 cases -> We throw **3,4** or **4,3** with them, then the sum is **7.**
- 1 case -> We throw **4** with both of them, then the sum is **8**.

Concluded: We have a total of **16** cases, and we have **1/16** chance for **2,** **2/16** chance for **3**,... and finally **1/16** chance again for **8**.

I don't really have any idea how to solve this task, so what exactly should I do to get two tetrahedrons, which have the same cases if I throw with them, but they are not like these?

Comment: What are the positive integers on their sides in the case of two tetrahedra? What does "It is 25% to throw either of them" mean? What, precisely, is the task you are trying to solve?

Comment: I meant with the 25% that you have 25% chance to throw 1,2,3 or 4, so it kind of means that it is regular.

Comment: We have the numbers: 1,2,3 and 4 on both of them, and we want to write other positive integers on them, and we want, that with these numbers, we still have the same chance for the sum of the two score.

Comment: Basically, the question is, that which are these integers? :)

Comment: Are you asking how we can relabel the sides of the tetrahedra with positive integers (not necessarily 1,2,3,4) so that the list of possible outcomes for the relabelled tetrahedra is the same as if the sides of both tetrahedra were labelled 1,2,3,4?

Comment: I think I can rephrase this: Let $X$ be a probability space of four elements, with each element having probability $0.25$. Let $C$ be a rv on $X$ that takes on the values $1, 2, 3, 4$. Find two positive-integer-valued random variables $A$ and $B$ on $X$, such that for $i = 2, \ldots, 8$, $$Pr_{u, v \in X \times X} \{A(u) + B(v) = i\} = Pr_{u, v \in X \times X}\{C(u) + C(v) = i\}$$.

Comment: The problem, if I'm getting your meaning, sounds like the tetrahedral case of the Crazy dice problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sicherman_dice

Comment: If you do all your arithmetic in $(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)$, the distribution outcome of the sum of two tetrahedral dice with faces $1,2,3,4$ will be exactly the same as the distribution of a single such die. In fact you can roll as many such dice as you want and add their values; same distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using positive integers and having the ability to throw 2 in only one way $\Rightarrow$ there must be one 1 on each die.

For getting 3 two ways, assuming we want some different numbers, we can try putting the two 2s on one die (the first); then the second die cannot have a 2.

To get 4 three ways, then, we need three 3s; these can't all be on the second die because that would give too many ways of making 5. So put two 3s on the second die and one on the first, which gives use four ways to make 5, and two (of three required) ways to make 6.

Add the last option for making 6 by putting a 5 on the second die, and it all works out for 7s and 8s:
$$
(1,2,2,3) \\
(1,3,3,5)
$$

Comment: A very nice and simple solution, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have your initial set of dice, but when you roll them, instead of just adding the numbers on the bottom faces, you add any number to the die on the left and subtract the same number from the die on the right? Does your total change? Instead of adding and subtracting "any number" after you roll the dice, why not do it before you roll them?